# В одном массиве есть строки, в другом URL. Как вывести вместе, чтоб при нажатии на строку был переход по ссылке?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив     $mass, в котором содержатся строки, 64 штуки. есть так же $mass2 в котором есть ссылки на строки. по индексу совпадают, то есть 0 ссылка ссылается на 0 строку и тд

как сделать так, чтоб вот эта штука работала для двух массивов, и выводилась вся таблица ссылок сразу?

```
echo "<a href='$mass2[0]'>$mass[0]</a>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую пованговать. Как я понял, тебе нужно в цикле вывести ссылки

```
$mass = ['home', 'about'];
$mass2 = ['/home', '/about'];

foreach ($mass as $key => $value) {
    echo "<a href='$mass2[$key]'>$value</a>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: да, спасибо огромное) чистый интерес, а как бы это выглядело в ассоциативном массиве?) если бы ключи - имена, а элементы - ссылки?

Comment: @inDee $key - ключ; $value - данные

Comment: `foreach ($mass as $key => $value) {
    echo "<a href='$value'>$key</a>";
}` Ключ - заголовок, значение - ссылка